# node-postgres queries not returning anything in Express routes async routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, node-postgres

I'm trying to run a simple query from an express route:

```
var router = require('express-promise-router')()
const { Pool } = require('pg')

const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'user',
  password: 'password',
  host: 'host',
  port: 1234,
  database: 'db'
})

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('OK')
  try {
    const { rows } = await pool.query('Select VERSION()')
    console.log(rows)
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
  console.log('DONE')
})
module.exports = router
```

'OK' Prints after sending the request but rows, e, or 'DONE' never print. I'm following the async/await method directly from https://node-postgres.com/guides/async-express.

I've also came across a thread for koa-router where people were having issues with async await calls because of some middle-ware they added that wasn't synchronous 
https://github.com/ZijianHe/koa-router/issues/358.

I'm not sure what middle-ware would cause this but here's my app.js that initializes all middle-ware:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');

var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cors = require("cors");
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var dataRouter = require("./routes/data");
var uploadRouter = require("./routes/upload")
var fundingRouter = require('./routes/chartData/fundingOverview')
var testRouter = require('./routes/test')
var authRouter = require('./routes/auth')
var session = require('express-session')
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)
var passport = require('passport')
const config = require('config')

const mongo = config.get('mongo')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect(mongo, {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useFindAndModify: false
}).then(res => {
  console.log('connected')
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
var express = require('express');
const mountRoutes = require('./routes')
var app = express();




const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
mountRoutes(app)
app.use(cors())


var sessionMiddleWare = session({
  secret: 'top session secret',
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  unset: 'destroy',
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: false,
    maxAge: 1000 * 3600 * 24,
    secure: false, // this need to be false if https is not used. Otherwise, cookie will not be sent.
  }
})
app.use(sessionMiddleWare)


// Run production React server on Node server

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
   app.use(express.static('client/build'))

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
})
}

// End Run production React Server on Node Server


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


// app.use('/upload', uploadRouter)
// app.use('/', indexRouter);
// app.use('/users', usersRouter);
// app.use('/data', dataRouter)
// app.use('/funding', fundingRouter)
// app.use('/login', usersRouter)
// app.use('/auth', authRouter)

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
// app.use(function(req, res, next) {
//   next(createError(404));
// });

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

I'm mounting the routes directly after body parser. That's the only middle-ware that's called before the routes and is required in order for me to get data into the back end.

I'm able to execute that simple query by putting it into a script file and running 'node test.js' (I.E without the router) and it works fine so I know it's not a problem with node-postgre.

I know this is a problem with the call stack not being totally synchronous but I'm confused as to what's not at this point. I even made the axios call on the front-end async/await with no luck (I don't think it was necessary though).

Any guidance would be help a lot.

EDIT:

I created a fresh express skeleton and hooked my front-end to make a call to a route on the new express server with the same code, it worked. It led me to discover the call wasn't being completed because I was running the server with Nodemon. When I start the server using 'yarn start' the async calls get processed correctly. The question now is what in nodemon makes async router calls not work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to finish the request/response cycle in your middleware.

So in your code:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('OK')
    try {
        const { rows } = await pool.query('Select VERSION()')
        console.log(rows)
        res.status(200).json(rows)
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.status(500).json(e)
    }
    console.log('DONE')
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. It feels like the query is getting hung up and no code after it can execute.

Comment: Are your database port correct? Your code shows `1234`, but default postgres port is `5432`

Comment: Yes, I'm able to execute the query in a regular script file and get a result, it just doesn't work when called in a router.